# Capture and Display error inside JqueryUI dialog

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using JQuery-UI dialog to load an MVC partial view

Here is some sample code:

```
$(function () {

function fSetupDialogs() {

    $("#dialog-popup").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      resizable: true,
      modal: true
    });
}
});



$('body').on('click', '.popup-Edit',
    function (e) {

        url = $(this).data("url");

        $("#dialog-popup")
            .load(url)
            .html("<img src='/content/images/Spinner.gif'>")
            .dialog("option", "title", "Edit " + url.split("/").pop())
            .dialog('open');

    }
);
```

This works pretty well despite some occasional weird scrollbars and stuff.

The problem is when the view throws an error, I can't work out how to inspect it and display it inside the jqueryui panel

So if the view returns a 500 or 401 error, I'd like to capture that and show it in the dialog. Right now what happens is that the spinner GIF just sits there forever. If I open the F12 console I can see the error in there.

I have tried using the `.error` event handler which does capture it and pop up a messagebox. But I want to display inside the popup:

```
        // This pops up an error alert
        $("#dialog-popup")
            .load(url)
            .error(alert("error"))
            .html("<img src='/content/images/Spinner.gif'>")
            .dialog("option", "title", "Edit " + url.split("/").pop())
            .dialog('open');
```

How do I display something inside the dialog? This has no effect - the spinner stays in there

```
        // This has no effect - I want to see the words "error" 
        $("#dialog-popup")
            .load(url)
            .error($("#dialog-popup").html("error"))
            .html("<img src='/content/images/Spinner.gif'>")
            .dialog("option", "title", "Edit " + url.split("/").pop())
            .dialog('open');
```

For bonus points, how do I use the javascript error object to identify 401, 500 whatever? - I haven't got to that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through my own code and found the answer.

The `load` method takes a callback argument that can be used to do what I need

I wrote a function called `popupComplete` that is called when the load is finished.

```
// This loads a partial MVC view into the popup
$("#dialog-popup")
    .load(url,popupComplete)
    .html("<div align='middle'><img src='/content/images/Spinner.gif'></div>")
    .dialog("option", "title", "New")
    .dialog("open");

// when the load is complete, this is called
// which optionally displays an error inside the popup
function popupComplete(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status === "error") {
        var msg =
            "<BR><BR><BR><H3 style='text-align: center;'><span style='color: red;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-fire'></span>   Confound it!<BR><BR>" +
            xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + 
            "<BR><BR>" + (xhr.status == 401 ? "Try logging in again" : "") +
            "</B></H3>";
        $("#dialog-popup").html(msg);
    }
}
```